# Redirect packages directed to port 5000 to another port

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to use eboard to connect to the FICS servers (http://www.freechess.org), but it fails because port 5000 is blocked (company firewall). However, I can connect to the server through the telnet port (23):

```
telnet freechess.org 23
(succeeds)
telnet freechess.org 5000 
(fails)
```

Unfortunately the port number is hardcoded (see here: http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1613075.html). I'd rather not have to hack the source code as the author of that thread ended up doing. Can I just forward the port on my local machine using iptables? I tried:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 5000 -j REDIRECT --to-port 23
```

and

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --src 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5000 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 23
```

but these didn't work...

Note that:

```
$ sudo iptables -t nat -L
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:5000 redir ports 23

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:5000 redir ports 23 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: Use sudo iptables -t nat -L   to list the nat table rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-j REDIRECT` redirects to your own machine. If you want to redirect to a different port on the remote machine, use `-j DNAT --to-destination :23`

Comment: Awesome, that worked: `sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT --src 0/0 -p tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination :23`

Comment: So how do you undo it?

Comment: @Will By removing the iptables rule again, with `sudo iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT 1` where `1` is the position of the rule in the chain.

Comment: Thanks @tumbleweed I googled a little harder and found a good explanation here http://serverfault.com/questions/288729/once-i-set-iptables-to-reroute-a-port-how-do-i-undo-it/418361#418361